Boot hangs with message ACPI Bios Error (bug): Could no resolve symbol[\SB.PCI0.DP.GV], AE_NOT_FOUND ACPI:Error Aborting method
_SB+PI0.RPUS.PCRP.ON due to  previous error {AE_NOT_FOUND]
I had an Ubuntu 20  I think(cannot get in to verify) which was working fine for over 2 years. When I get an undate message I usually update, so I presume this was after some update. The problem is
a) I cannot log in. How do I log in?
b) new kernels have iso that are too large to fit on a dvd, so I cannot do a clean install either.

you can use USB flash drive to make clean installation.

I guess also a double layer DVD
